# How to control a Visual Studio's extension from custom command?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I have a SerialMonitor extension in VS2019 which is let's say connected to COM3.
I have also created a custom command named "Arduino Upload" to upload my compiled stuff to COM3.

Now, when I want to run my upload, first I need to go to the SerialMonitor and disconnect COM3 port, then click the "Arduino Upload" button and then connect COM3 again.

I would like to automate this.

Means, the upload command should do these three steps:

1. Tell SerialMonitor extension to disconnect COM3
2. Upload my stuff to COM3 (I already have a command for this)
3. Tell SerialMonitor extension to connect COM3

So now, as a general question, is there a way how to tell VS extension to do something from custom command?

(The question is really meant generally. I guess that this particular SerialMonitor extension is not capable of this. But I'm interested whether it is even possible to code an extension this way.)

Comment: There's not really a general mechanism for something like this, at least not that broadly applies to all types of extensions.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski: Ok. So as there is not any general interface for this in extension's API, it looks like it must be done individually via Interprocess Communication. Pipes or sockets come to my mind as the simplest solution.

Comment: Could you please share a small sample about the issue with us?

Comment: @Perry Qian-MSFT: I have started to play with Arduino but I don't like its native Arduino IDE. I'm quite skillful with VisualStudio so I setup VS to build my Arduino solution and it works perfectly. I have created custom command to upload my built code to Arduino hw but for this to work, the used COM port needs to be not used by other apps. But my SerialMonitor extension is using this COM port, naturally. So, before upload I need to go to SerialMonitor and disconnect COM port, then do the upload, and then connect COM port in SerialMonitor again.